# Calling mvn archetype:create-from-project on a simple archetype:webapp project is asking for Setting.xml

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-archetype

I am following [this instruction](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/advanced-usage.html) to understand `maven` archetype.
Calling `mvn archetype:create-from-project` on a simple webapp project asking me to have `setting.xml` file under `.m2` dir.

Not sure why it's asking, was not able to found any specific reason behind this.Neither any doc state to create for any local project.

Please help if you give a clear picture .
Attaching the error while running the command.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] -------------------------< com.example:myapp >--------------------------
[INFO] Building myapp Maven Webapp 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:create-from-project (default-cli) > generate-sources @ myapp >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:create-from-project (default-cli) < generate-sources @ myapp <<<
[INFO]
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:create-from-project (default-cli) @ myapp ---
[INFO] Setting default groupId: com.example
[INFO] Setting default artifactId: myapp
[INFO] Setting default version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] Setting default package: com.example
[WARN] Maven will be executed in interactive mode, but no input stream has been configured for this MavenInvoker instance.
[ERROR] Error executing Maven.
[ERROR] The specified user settings file does not exist: C:\Users\Rajat Dobriyal\.m2\settings.xml
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  5.303 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-06T00:38:43+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.1.2:create-from-project (default-cli) on project myapp: Invoker process ended with result different than 0! -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 7):

`settings.xml` is not created during installation, that's why you need to create a default settings file under `C:\Users\Rajat Dobriyal\.m2\settings.xml` with content:

```
    <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                          https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
    </settings>
```

More detailed is [here](https://maven.apache.org/settings.html)

Comment: Thanks. But what is the reason it goes for settings.xml . Even after there is no such configuration out there. And while seeing any of tutorial none of those even mentioned about settings.xml